# Run WebView from AsyncTask to do a login

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-webview, runnable

In our Android Application we have to do REST-Calls from an AsyncTask so we do not block the UI.
The server is using openID login, so we have to display a WebView for the user to get a valid, authenticated cookie.

As the server is requesting authentication from time to time also after a valid login, we have to display the WebView again. (It is mainly because of permissions, and we cannot change this behaviour.)

The question now is, how can we execute the AsyncTask, then if needed display a WebView in the UI, wait for the user to authenticate and then return to the AsyncTask WITHOUT loosing the AsyncTask. This is essential as some requests have to get further processing in the backend after the user authenticated.

The main thought is to execute a Runnable using "runOnUiThread" from the AsyncTask. But I cannot really understand how to display the WebView from there and then finish the Runnable when the user input is finished.
(We already did this in a WebViewActivity, with "onPageFinished", so that is not the problem, just the combination with the Runnable)

Anybody suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if I fully understood the question, but the main goal ist to load a `WebView` once the `AsyncTask` is done, right?

There is this method in `AsyncTask`called `onPostExecute()` where you can perform your UI-dependent-tasks.

Here's a sample code snipplet:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(HttpResult result)
{
    if (HttpStatus.SC_OK == result.getStatusCode())
        callback.onSuccess(result.getXmlResponse());
    else
        callback.onError(result.getStatusCode());
}
```

The `HttpResult` was a custom class for the generic `AsyncTask` parameter in order to encapsule some of the Info of the response.

Comment: No, its during the AsyncTask. So we can pause the execution of the AsyncTask, show the WebView, authenticate the user and then resume the execution of the AsyncTask.

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood the question then :-(
Can you not split the task in two seperat AsyncTasks and hand over important data via the result parameter? That way you could lanch the WebView in between.

Comment: If you really want to use the same AsyncTask, you could use the java wait-notify mechanism. Define an object "waiter", call waiter.wait() in the asynctask after showing the webview. The when the webview is done, call waiter.notify() on the UI thread to continue execution of the task